# Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'last_activity' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to build an application with Codeigniter 2.2.
When I decided to use Session library I created the ci_sessions table as it was written in the user guide:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
  `session_id` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_address` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_agent` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_data` text COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `ci_sessions`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
 ADD KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`);
```

In one of my controllers I had this error message:

A Database Error Occurred

```
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'last_activity' in 'field list'
UPDATE `ci_sessions` SET `last_activity` = 1445764364, `user_data` = '{\"user_data\":\"\",\"status\":true,\"username\":\"mhpr92\"}' WHERE `session_id` = '0a982cdec361137b37e88654e489390a'
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\my_application\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 331
```

and when I tried to execute the query manually in phpmyadmin I got the same result.

Comment: So how about going to phpmyadmin table structure and see if field really exists?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with either the query or the CREATE TABLE statement so you must be using the wrong database

Comment: It does exist ... as you can see the way I created the table.
`last_activity int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',`

Comment: Noteworthy, this error only occurs when trying to insert JSON or serialized text like this 
a:2:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:8:"username";s:6:"mhpr92";}
and insists even when I tried to strip the string of symbols and replace them with html ascii HTML number. like this } =>&#125;.